# How to Jenkins Groovy scripting for live fetching of Docker image + authentication

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have a script groovy, this script for live fetching of docker image,
I want to add the authentication function with the private repository, but I am not familiar with groovy, who can help me, thanks

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
// Set the URL we want to read from, it is MySQL from official Library for this example, limited to 20 results only.
docker_image_tags_url = "https://registry.adx.abc/v2/mysql/tags/list"
try {
    // Set requirements for the HTTP GET request, you can add Content-Type headers and so on...
    def http_client = new URL(docker_image_tags_url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    http_client.setRequestMethod('GET')
    // Run the HTTP request
    http_client.connect()
    // Prepare a variable where we save parsed JSON as a HashMap, it's good for our use case, as we just need the 'name' of each tag.
    def dockerhub_response = [:]    
    // Check if we got HTTP 200, otherwise exit
    if (http_client.responseCode == 200) {
        dockerhub_response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(http_client.inputStream.getText('UTF-8'))
    } else {
        println("HTTP response error")
        System.exit(0)
    }
    // Prepare a List to collect the tag names into
    def image_tag_list = []
    // Iterate the HashMap of all Tags and grab only their "names" into our List
    dockerhub_response.results.each { tag_metadata ->
        image_tag_list.add(tag_metadata.name)    
    }
    // The returned value MUST be a Groovy type of List or a related type (inherited from List)
    // It is necessary for the Active Choice plugin to display results in a combo-box
    return image_tag_list.sort()
} catch (Exception e) {
         // handle exceptions like timeout, connection errors, etc.
         println(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved, thank you everyone for your help

```
// Import the JsonSlurper class to parse Dockerhub API response
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
// Set the URL we want to read from, it is MySQL from official Library for this example, limited to 20 results only.
docker_image_tags_url = "https://registry.adx.vn/v2/form-be/tags/list"
try {
    // Set requirements for the HTTP GET request, you can add Content-Type headers and so on...
    def http_client = new URL(docker_image_tags_url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    http_client.setRequestMethod('GET')

    String userCredentials = "your_user:your_passwd";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));

    http_client.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
    
    // Run the HTTP request
    http_client.connect()
    // Prepare a variable where we save parsed JSON as a HashMap, it's good for our use case, as we just need the 'name' of each tag.
    def dockerhub_response = [:]    
    // Check if we got HTTP 200, otherwise exit
    if (http_client.responseCode == 200) {
        dockerhub_response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(http_client.inputStream.getText('UTF-8'))
    } else {
        println("HTTP response error")
        System.exit(0)
    }
    // Prepare a List to collect the tag names into
    def image_tag_list = []
    // Iterate the HashMap of all Tags and grab only their "names" into our List
    dockerhub_response.tags.each { tag_metadata ->
        image_tag_list.add(tag_metadata)    
    }
    // The returned value MUST be a Groovy type of List or a related type (inherited from List)
    // It is necessary for the Active Choice plugin to display results in a combo-box
    return image_tag_list.sort()
} catch (Exception e) {
         // handle exceptions like timeout, connection errors, etc.
         println(e)
}
```

here is the result
[image]